# How can I tell what object file format my code will be?

Tags: assembly, gcc, clang

I'm reading up on assembly code, and I created a "hello world" C file to compile down to assembly:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main() {
  4   printf("Hello world\n");
  5   return 0;
  6 }
```

I compiled it with GCC, using the command `gcc -S hello.c`.  The result was the following:

```
  1         .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  2         .build_version macos, 10, 15    sdk_version 10, 15, 6
  3         .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
  4         .p2align        4, 0x90
  5 _main:                                  ## @main
  6         .cfi_startproc
  7 ## %bb.0:
  8         pushq   %rbp
  9         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
 10         .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
 11         movq    %rsp, %rbp
 12         .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
 13         subq    $16, %rsp
 14         movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
 15         leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
 16         movb    $0, %al
 17         callq   _printf
 18         xorl    %ecx, %ecx
 19         movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
 20         movl    %ecx, %eax
 21         addq    $16, %rsp
 22         popq    %rbp
 23         retq
 24         .cfi_endproc
 25                                         ## -- End function
 26         .section        __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
 27 L_.str:                                 ## @.str
 28         .asciz  "Hello world\n"
 29 
 30 
 31 .subsections_via_symbols
```

I am trying to understand the above output line-by-line (starting with the first line which uses the `.section` directive), and one of the references I'm using is this link at [sourceware.org](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html), which appears to be the most authoritative source of information on the GCC assembler (although let me know if I'm wrong on that).

The first two sections of the reference guide are titled `COFF Version` and `ELF Version`, and I'm inferring that it will be important for me to know which version my compiler is using in order to get the most out of my self-studies.

The output of `gcc -v` is the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

My question is- what are the ways I could deduce whether my GCC configuration is using COFF or ELF?  Is it apparent from looking at the output code?  Or would I have to somehow print out the configuration options my version of GCC is using?

Comment: Assembly code is neither ELF nor COFF; those are formats of executables. Why you just assemble something, you don't get an executable, just a binary object.

Comment: The object format will be Mach-O btw.

Comment: @fuz I appreciate the tip about the object format, but I'm actually more interested in learning how I could have answered this question for myself (i.e. I'm more interested in learning how to fish than being given a fish).  Are there flags I can pass to `gcc` which would tell me the answer?  Or are there any clues in the output code which would give away the answer?

Comment: @RichieThomas So, Mach-O is the standard object file format under macOS (your assembly source says it's for macOS).  Barring fairly esoteric scenarios, all object files produced for macOS will be in Mach-O format.  This is common knowledge and probably documented somewhere.  I don't really know how to figure this out programatically.  Perhaps take an object file and run the `file` command on it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @einpoklum.  The link I referenced seems to imply that different directives (like `.section` on line 1 of the assembly code I pasted) will be passed different arguments depending on whether ELF or COFF is used for the target.  Therefore it seems like I'll need to know which of the two my machine uses in order to know which API to reference.  Happy to rephrase my question if you think it will increase its accuracy, but I think my larger question (how to tell which of the two types of file will be generated) still stands.

Comment: @fuz yes I'm indeed using macOS.  Happy to go off the assumption that the output object file format will be Mach-O if that's the standard for my OS.  I'm sure you're right that it's documented somewhere.  Thanks again.

Comment: @fuz just for clarification, is it accurate to say that Mach-O, ELF, and COFF are all object file formats, and that the output I can expect will be *neither* ELF nor COFF, but rather Mach-O?

Comment: @RichieThomas Yes, that is correct.  Note that macOS uses its own assembler with a syntax similar to that of the GNU assembler, so the contents of that manual do not necessarily apply.

Comment: `Note that macOS uses its own assembler with a syntax similar to that of the GNU assembler, so the contents of that manual do not necessarily apply.`. That explains a lot of my struggles up to this point.  Thanks again @fuz

Comment: It's honestly kind of a mess; clang might even use its own internal assembler, I haven't checked.  There used to be some documentation on that online, but ever since Apple has removed all the old stuff from its website, it's a bit hard to find.  it's really a shame how poorly the toolchain is documented these days.  However, given that it works basically the same way on all Unices, it's easy to deduce the details once you are familiar with the toolchain of any one UNIX.

Comment: I saw [a Hacker News article](https://www.caseyliss.com/2020/11/10/on-apples-pisspoor-documentation) about that very same topic the other day.  I had no idea the problem was that bad.  Glad to know what to expect as I dive into Mach-O internals.